# Linux is spamming me now (anacron)

Tags: debian, logs, email, logrotate, anacron

Since about a year ago, linux Debian has been spamming me with messages like the following:

```
Subject: Anacron job 'cron.daily' on mymachine
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
Date: Mon,  3 Apr 2017 07:35:04 -0400 (EDT)

/etc/cron.daily/logrotate:
reading config file /etc/logrotate.conf
including /etc/logrotate.d
reading config file apt
reading config file aptitude
reading config file consolekit
reading config file dpkg
reading config file exim4-base
reading config file exim4-paniclog
reading config file firebird2.5
reading config file iptraf
reading config file mumble-server
reading config file pm-utils
reading config file ppp
reading config file rsyslog
reading config file samba
reading config file speech-dispatcher
reading config file unattended-upgrades
reading config file winbind

Handling 23 logs

rotating pattern: /var/log/apt/term.log  monthly (12 rotations)
empty log files are not rotated, old logs are removed
considering log /var/log/apt/term.log
  log does not need rotating

rotating pattern: /var/log/apt/history.log  monthly (12 rotations)
empty log files are not rotated, old logs are removed
considering log /var/log/apt/history.log
  log does not need rotating

rotating pattern: /var/log/aptitude  monthly (6 rotations)
empty log files are not rotated, old logs are removed
considering log /var/log/aptitude
  log does not need rotating

rotating pattern: /var/log/ConsoleKit/history  monthly (6 rotations)
empty log files are not rotated, old logs are removed
considering log /var/log/ConsoleKit/history
  log does not need rotating

rotating pattern: /var/log/dpkg.log  monthly (12 rotations)
empty log files are not rotated, old logs are removed
considering log /var/log/dpkg.log
  log does not need rotating

rotating pattern: /var/log/alternatives.log  monthly (12 rotations)
empty log files are not rotated, old logs are removed
considering log /var/log/alternatives.log
```

(1) Is there a way I can stop this with a single setting or do I need to individually find the motivation for each spam type and address it separately?

(2) If I need to solve this problem, one spam at a time, how do I deal with the anacron issue pasted above?

(3) Why is this happening now? I have had my Debian machine for at least 6 years and it is only since about a year or so that I started getting spammed and right now I have 577 messages in my mailbox of this type.

Comment: I think you changed some flags in logrotate, to print debug information.

Comment: ... what happened a year ago? are the configurations kept under version control?

Comment: You should be able to set a null MAILTO in the /etc/cron.daily/logrotate file.
 `MAILTO=`

Answer (score 3):

If you login as root and run

```
/usr/sbin/logrotate -v /etc/logrotate.conf
```

you will get that output on the screen. The problem is the `-v` which you have to remove. You will find the `-v` here:

```
$ grep -r logrotate /etc/cron*
```

Example output:

```
/etc/cron.daily/logrotate:test -x /usr/sbin/logrotate || exit 0
/etc/cron.daily/logrotate:/usr/sbin/logrotate -v /etc/logrotate.conf
```

When `cron` get some output it would by default be mailed to user `root`.